# Removing loading screen and spinner after all contents of the window have loaded but before iframes have finished loading

Tags: flask, iframe, window, jinja2, loading

I am using a loading screen with a spinner that is displayed before all contents in the window have loaded. It works well on all pages and the window loads very fast on webpages with less content but on one of my pages, I am loading many iframes that embed youtube videos. `$(window).on('load', function(){});` doesn't trigger until all contents have loaded, including iframes. That means that loading takes a long time and the loading screen with the spinner is shown long after the browser has finished loading the HTML, CSS, JS, and all images. I want to use skeleton loading for the iframes after the HTML, CSS, JS, and all images have loaded to cut down on perceived load time. Is there a way to tell that the rest of the window has fully loaded but the iframes are still loading? This is what I am currently doing to remove the loading screen with the spinner:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<div class="spinner-wrapper">
  <div class="spinner">
    <div class="rect1"></div>
    <div class="rect2"></div>
    <div class="rect3"></div>
    <div class="rect4"></div>
    <div class="rect5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<body>
 {% for video in range(videos|length) %}
   <iframe class="yvideo" src="{{ "https://www.youtube.com/embed/%s" + videos[video]}.get("url") }}"></iframe>
 {% endfor %}
 <script type=module src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/video.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

videos.js:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    preloaderFadeOutTime = 300;
    function hidePreloader() {
    var preloader = $('.spinner-wrapper');
        preloader.fadeOut(preloaderFadeOutTime);
    }
    hidePreloader();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be multiple ways to solve this issue:

One simple approach can be to keep source of iframes empty initially and dynamically set source of iframes upon window.load.

Here sample code:

```
 <script>
    $(window).on('load', function() {

        document.getElementById('myIframe').src = "your URL";
        document.getElementById('myIframe2').src = "your URL";

       preloaderFadeOutTime = 300;
       function hidePreloader() {
         var preloader = $('.spinner-wrapper');
         preloader.fadeOut(preloaderFadeOutTime);
       }
       hidePreloader();
    });
  </script>

  <iframe id="myIframe"  src="" ></iframe>
  <iframe id="myIframe2"  src="" ></iframe>
```

EDIT:
If you cannot change the video.js file but can create your own js files which can interact with html on the page then do below in your custom js file:

```
//your external js
// first get collection of your iframes by class
 var listOfIframes = document.getElementsByClassName("yvideo");
 for (let item of listOfIframes) {
            item.src = "";  // set them to empty.
        }
 window.addEventListener("load", function() { 

//once page is loaded then populate the source with your json file. 


 for (let item of listOfIframes) {
            item.src = "URLs from JSON";  
        }

 });
```

### Second approach:

Instead of calling hidePreloader() only at window.load.  You can also check for the rest of the items in your page that if they are loaded or not.  Once they are loaded, then you can use call hidePreloader()

Comment: I am using a CSP that allows JS in the static directory of my web framework (Flask) but not inline scripting to protect from XSS attacks, so I can't set anything inline. Also, the URLs are not predetermined. I make a call to the YouTube API every so often to get the URLs for all the videos on a specific channel and store them in a JSON file. In the request for the URLs, the JSON file is read and the URLs are implemented by looping through the JSON object via Jinja2. So basically I'm not sure if I can do this. However, would making an XHR request work for this?

Comment: The solution which i provided earlier is much simpler then XHR.  if you can parse the JSON file and assign the source to iframes in your window.load then you are good to go.

Comment: Right but as I was saying I can't do that because my content security policy is set up so that I don't allow for inlining scripting, and I don't want to change that. So I can create JS files in my static folder which are sent in a response to a GET request on the endpoint and can interact with the HTML elements but I can't store what is being written by Jinja2 to the template, in the JS file becuase it isn't an inline script. I'll update my code so you can see what I'm doing.

Comment: Right, now i see your code structure and that you have limitations.  But still if you can create js files which can interact with the elements then you can do this.  I will update my answer.

Comment: How can I serve the data in the JSON file in a GET request that's stored in the static folder while also trying to render the HTML template? Flask doesn't automatically server the JSON file in the static folder on the client-side unless I can implement it somehow by avoiding the use of XHR requests.

Comment: With this limitations, then maybe you can check when rest of your page is loaded and then call hidePreloader(). I will add second approach in the answer.